# Past meeting was moved in my Calendar screen after organizer late changed its date

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have attended a weekly meeting yesterday at 12pm (July 22nd, French "22 juillet") and the organizer has sent an email right after the meeting to provide the meeting notes, and at the same time he changed the date of the meeting so that to organize a new meeting next week (July 29th, French "29 juillet"), as you can see here:

[image]

Unfortunately, that automatically modified my Calendar view by moving the meeting item from July 22nd to July 29th (even before I accepted the meeting of next week), consequently my Calendar is no more a reliable view of my past meetings (if I need to check some things).

[image]

I understand that the organizer should create a new meeting instead of updating the date, but his error has a consequence on my own Calendar view. I don't want Outlook change things without informing me.

Is there a way to deactivate this automatic deletion of past meeting items whose dates are changed after the meeting has occurred? At least, Outlook should ask me what I want to do in that case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to deactivate this automatic deletion of past meeting items whose dates are changed after the meeting has occurred?

As I know, it is by design that calendar will automatically changed based on the time of your meetings and we could not change this. When the organizer change the meeting time, you will receive an email message which tells you the changes of this meetings. And if you have not enabled the "Auto Accept/Decline" option, it will shows shadows on your calendar until you accept the change like below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for confirming my fear, I hope that a new feature will be developed, as it's quite unpleasant to see the past events be removed from my Outlook by other people although these events actually occurred. And, although it was not my question, thank you for the information about the "shadows" to show if it's accepted or not.